# Why the milliseconds of datetime field in MYSQL is sometimes displayed as 000?

Tags: mysql, datetime

Why the milliseconds of datetime field in MYSQL is sometimes displayed as 000? MYSQL version is 5.5,the type of the column is datetime(3), it's java.util.Date in java code.Does anyone know why? And how to solve this problem ?

```
Preparing:insert into act_hi_comment(id_,time_,user_id_,task_id_)values(?,?,?,?)
Parameters:55909,2020-05-14 18:10:10.832(Timestamp),356(String),786908(String)
```

But,the time is displayed as 2020-05-14 18:10:10.000 in database

the command of create table is:

```
create table 'act_hi_comment'('id_' varchar(64) collate utf8_bin not null,'time_' datetime(3) default null,'user_id_' varchar(255) collate utf8_bin default null,'task_id_' varchar(64) collate utf8_bin default null,primary key ('id_')) engine=innoDB default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_bin;
```

Comment: the length of datetime is 3,some data is correct,and some is wrong(without the milliseconds of datetime).

Comment: If a column is defined as `DATETIME` is have **NO** fractional seconds part. Alter it to `DATETIME(frac)`, where `frac` is the needed amount of digits in fractional part, from 1 to 6.

Comment: Yes, it is defined as datetime(3)@Akina

Comment: If the value with 3 fractional digits have them zeroed after inserting into the table than look does Java transfers them to the table. Enable General log temporarily and look what final INSERT query text is sent to MySQL.

Comment: Because this is a production environment, I can‘t open the mysql temporary log. I got the log of the server. This part is recorded by mybatis. I don’t know if it can be used as a reference.  I updated the question,added the content of sql in the mybats log

Comment: This is NOT the log we need. You must find the way to receive SQL text transferred to MySQL, after parameters inserted into. PS. Add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE act_hi_comment;` command into the question text.

Comment: I got the content of this sql, the sql text is ：insert into act_hi_comment(id_,time_,user_id_,task_id_)values(\'55909\',\'2020-05-14 18:10:10\',\'356\',\'786908\')，But I don't know why, The parameters are printed in mybatis, and it seems that the next step is to execute the writeTo method of MySQLQuery in mariadb to write the sql to the OutputStream and then commit the transaction.

Comment: *I got the content of this sql, the sql text is ：`insert into act_hi_comment(id_,time_,user_id_,task_id_)values(\'55909\',\'2020-05-14 18:10:10\',\'356\',\'786908\')`* - this shows that it is not MySQL issue but Java issue which truncates fractional part of datetime value. Try to convert datetime to string with fractional digits and transfer it to MySQL as string-typed parameter.

Comment: It is unlikely because the insertion action and entity object are in the third-party API.

Comment: trouble-sadness...

Answer (score 0):

As @Akina correctly mentions in the comments, by default DATETIME does not have fractional seconds. That said after MySQL 5.6 they can be [enabled](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) in the column definition. From the manual:

```
CREATE TABLE fractest( c1 TIME(2), c2 DATETIME(2), c3 TIMESTAMP(2) );
INSERT INTO fractest VALUES ('17:51:04.777', '2018-09-08 17:51:04.777', '2018-09-08 17:51:04.777');
```

will yield

```
+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| c1          | c2                     | c3                     |
+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| 17:51:04.78 | 2018-09-08 17:51:04.78 | 2018-09-08 17:51:04.78 |
+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: I defined it as datetime(3)